# unable to remove an array and property (multiple) from an object while submitting using reactjs

Tags: javascript

My objective is to remove an array[] and some properties from an object. I can remove one property from an object by `delete` method but when I want to remove multiples then it is showing error like `The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.`

`Experience` array is having an object, it may have multiple objects.

```
experience: [
    {
        organisation: "",
        id: "",
        from: "",
        to: "",
        skills: [],
        achievements: 0,
    },
    {
        organisationName: "",
        id: "",
        from: "",
        to: "",
        skills: [],
        achievements: 0,
    }
]
```

this is the code:

```
let skillsArray = this.state.experiences.map((item) => {
  let newItem = { ...item }
  delete newItem.skills;
  delete newItem.achievements;
  return newItem;
})
```

Can anyone help me in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a TypeScript compiler error, not a JavaScript runtime error. The shape of a `newItem` is the same as the original `item`, and the original `item` sounds to have required `skills` and `achievements` properties, so removing them via `delete` is not permitted (because then the existing object would not match the shape it was typed as).

For similar reasons, the following is not permitted either:

```
const obj = {
    foo: 'val1',
    bar: 'val2',
};
delete obj.foo;
```

(because the type of `obj`, which is `{ foo: string; bar: string; }` would be incorrect if `foo` was deleted)

You can destructure the undesirable properties out instead, and use rest syntax to collect the properties for the new object:

```
let skillsArray = this.state.experiences.map((item) => {
  const { skills, achievements, ...newItem } = item;
  return newItem;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `delete` use `map` and in the callback function return only required keys

```js
let experience = [{
    organisation: "",
    id: "",
    from: "",
    to: "",
    skills: [],
    achievements: 0,
  },
  {
    organisationName: "",
    id: "",
    from: "",
    to: "",
    skills: [],
    achievements: 0,
  }
];

let newExp = experience.map((item) => {
  return {
    organisationName: item.organisationName,
    id: item.id,
    from: item.from,
    to: item.to,
  }
});

console.log(newExp)
```